# Need to do split screen into two parts and play the video . (android)

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview, google-cardboard

I need to split the screen into 2 dia, not `LinearLayout`. That's not good for me because I need to play the video.

Here's a sample application ([by google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funghisoft.sbsvideoplayer&hl=ru)).it will be used for Google Cardboard, as I said above I need to do a synchronized video playback for both application examples. In what way can I implement it and which way to go?

If there is a link or code examples will be very happy.(*[example library](https://github.com/frma71/sbs)*)

Comment: `That's not good for me because I need to play the video.` Your choice: either play **an already splitted video** or play **2 videos**. I'd prefer the `first` option. All this can be made using a **single LinearLayout**.

Comment: @dergolem, Well, not much hunting to cut video , because somehow did the same splitting video into 2 parts like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mobius.vrcinema

Comment: So, it's enough when you evenly divide your LinearLayout into 2 Views using **weights**. And keep your players **in sync** (**this** is the challege).

Comment: @dergolem, and how to synchronize the video playback at all? Do you have examples of such synchronization ? To play in my Projects I'm using now SurfaceView and VideoView.

Comment: I have no clue. That's also why I would go for the first solution (where all the stereograms are only **visually** separated, but still a single entity).

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this?